# AttributeError: 'tokenizer' object has no attribute 'sent_tokenize'

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

When I run the below code gives me the following error:
 `AttributeError: 'tokenizer' object has no attribute 'sent_tokenize'` on the line `sentence_token= self.sent_tokenize(input_data)`.

Why does it give me that error?

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, \word_tokenize, WordPunctTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import brown
class tokenizer:
    input_data=''
    def __init__(self, input_data='', ):
        self.input_data = input_data

    def gen_SentTokenizers(self,input_data):
        sentence_token= self.sent_tokenize(input_data)  # Error!
        return sentence_token

    def gen_WordTokenizers(self, input_data):
        word_token=self.word_tokenize(input_data)
        return word_token

    def gen_WordPunctToken(self, input_data):
        word_PunctToken=self.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(input_data)
        return word_PunctToken

if __name__=='__main__':
    input_data = ' '.join(brown.words())
    token1 = tokenizer()
    token2 = tokenizer()
    token3 = tokenizer()

    token1.gen_SentTokenizers(input_data)
    print("\nSentence tokenizer:")
    print(token1)

    token2.gen_WordPunctToken(input_data)
    print("\nWord punct tokenizer:")
    print(token2)

    token3.gen_WordTokenizers(input_data)
    print("\nWord tokenizer:")
    print(token3)
```

Comment: `sent_tokenize` is a function, it can be used directly when given the string (paragraph/document) as the input.

Answer (score 3):

On terminal:

```
pip install --upgrade nltk
python -m nltk.downloader popular
```

In code:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
text = 'This str has many sentences. A sentence here. A sentence there.'
sent_tokenize(text)
```